# Page not scaling to larger screen sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am a newbie with bootstrap and really need help with this problem. I am trying to develop a single page website with bootstrap. It works fine with my laptop screen size but when I view it on a larger lcd of 1280px x 1024p, the page doesn't scale down to fill the viewport.

Here is a link to my code [Code](http://www.codeply.com/go/ZnFQzXZRwm)

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post what your viewport meta tag code is

Comment: @DarrenSweeney the viewport tag is <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: Try this `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,  minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney It still leaves half of the viewport empty on that particular resolution which is 1280px x 1024px

Answer (score 0):

Your site doesn't fill up the entire screen, because you only use a `col-lg-8`. The `.row` class of bootstrap can contain up to 12 columns and you're only using 8. So if you want it to take up the entire screen, you might want to change it to `col-lg-12`.

But even then, not the enitre screen will be taken up by the carousel, because you are using a `container` class. If you want it to use (almost) the entire width of the screen, you should use `container-fluid`.

So the first part of your snippet should look like this:

`<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-12">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
               <!-- Indicators -->
               <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
               </ol>`

Comment: I have another div beside the carousel. You can view it here [link] (http://azurepublishing.com/fairdeals/test/Test/)

I'm giving 75% of the screen width to the carousel and 25% to another div as shown in the link above. 

That's not solving the issue

Comment: In the example above, you have to change the `container`-class to `container-fluid` class. That makes it fill up the entire screen. `container-fluid` is the one you're going to use if you want it to take up the entire screen as mentioned in the above answer. For the 75% 25% you should use `col-lg-8` for the left div and `col-lg-4` for the right, or the other way around. That should really fix it.

Comment: Here is the code (http://www.codeply.com/go/B1WkiOnyDu) that I've been working on. For mobile it looks good but if you view it on larger screen sizes, you will see more than 60% of the viewport is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want something to happen based on the window height, you're going to need CSS [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). Depending on the screensize, the media query will express itself. An example for you is as follows:

#### CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-height: 480px) {
    .col-lg-8 {
        background-color: red;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-height: 380px) {
    .col-lg-8 {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

If you put this in a linked stylesheet and scale the website vertically, you can see that the `div` tags with `class="col-lg-8"` will either turn red or blue. Now you'll have to see for yourself where you want the borders to go.

Comment: Here is the jpg http://picpaste.com/problem-vFiGajwD.JPG. The blue arrow denotes the place of problem. The resolution of thi screen was 1280px x 1024px and can you see that it leaves all this white area empty. I want it to scale down to the full screen size.

Comment: Are you talking about the height?

Comment: Yes! I want it to be the height of the viewport